# Quiero leer el valor de una linea que ingrese mediante consola en kotlin en java era con scanf

Tags: kotlin

Estoy iniciando en kotlin quisiera saber como leer una linea escrita por mi en consola para algo sencillo por ejemplo

La consola me muestra
Igrese primer numero.
Luego ingreso el valor y lo almaceno en una variable

En java se hacia con scanf pero quiero saber como se hace en kotlin

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma nativa es con `readLine()`. Ejemplo:

```
fun main() {
    println("Ingresa tu nombre")
    val name = readLine()
    println("Hola $name")
}
```

`readLine()` retorna una string. Para convertirlo a otro tipo debes usar funciones como `toInt()`, `toLong()`, `toDouble()`, etc. Este es un ejemplo más complejo

```
fun main() {
    var n1: Int?
    var n2: Int?
    println("Ingresa el primer número")
    n1 = readLine()?.toIntOrNull()
    while (n1 == null) {
        println("El número ingresado no es válido")
        n1 = readLine()?.toIntOrNull()
    }
    println("Ingresa el segundo número")
    n2 = readLine()?.toIntOrNull()
    while (n2 == null) {
        println("El número ingresado no es válido")
        n2 = readLine()?.toIntOrNull()
    }
    println("El resultado es ${n1 + n2}")
}
```

Cuando trabajas sobre la JVM, Kotlin es 100% interoperable con Java así que también puedes seguir usando la clase `Scanner` de Java.

```
import java.util.Scanner
fun main() {
    val sc = Scanner(System.`in`)
    println("Ingresa tu nombre")
    val name = sc.nextLine()
    println("Hola $name")
}
```

Comment: Y en caso de val n1: int?  El signo ? Cual es su funcion?

Comment: Esa es una pregunta muy básica que fácilmente puedes encontrar en la [documentación](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-syntax.html#nullable-values-and-null-checks). En resumen significa que el tipo de dato es nullable, es decir que su valor puede ser `null`. A diferencia de Java, Kotlin es null-safe entonces debes especificar si quieres que tu variable sea nulable o no

Comment: Ok muchas gracias seguire investigando